# Send Custom Data to quote table

Tags: checkout, sales-order, custom-options, quote, extension-attributes

I am new to magento 2. I have created a custom checkout step where user can select delivery day and time via dropdown. Dropdown options are coming from system.xml via customConfigProvider after seller sets available days and time. Now i want to send the day and time option selected by user at checkout to quote and sales_order table.
I have already created columns in those tables but how can i send data when customer places order?

This is my js file

```
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator,
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_module/select-date'
            },

            dayData : window.checkoutConfig.day,
            timeData : window.checkoutConfig.time,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
            stepTitle: 'Day and Time',


            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    this.isVisible,
                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },


            navigate: function () {

            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

my html file

```
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
    <div id="checkout-step-title" class="step-content" data-role="content">
            <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
                <h4 style="padding-bottom: 1rem;padding-top: 1rem;">Select Delivery Day</h4>
                <select options="dayData" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"> </select>
                <h4 style="padding-bottom: 1rem;padding-top: 1rem;">Select Delivery Time</h4>
                <select options="timeData" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"> </select>
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary" style="height: 2rem; width: 5rem;">
                        <span>Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

My extension_attribute.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_day" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

di.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout_custom_shipping_block" xsi:type="object">RolusTech\DateAndTime\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the js file you need to send data via ajax

```
    function transfer() {
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const str = 'day='+ document.getElementById('dayData').value + '&time=' + document.getElementById('timeData').value
            const url='http://magento2/dateandtime/index/placeorder?' + str;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();

            Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                console.log(Http.responseText)
            }
        }
```

Then get the data in your controller and save it in quote table via quoteRepository. Then you can get data from quote table and save it in sales_order table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following things:

> 1. You have to add data to the additional data to the payment data. Create a function as following:

```
getData: function () {
      return {
      'method': 'custompayment',
      'additional_data': {
      'day_data': dayData,
      'time_data': timeData,
      // 'time_data': $('#timedata').val()
   }
```

> 2. Now you have to create an event and observer to get this data on Place Order. Create an events.xml file in etc folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="sales_order_payment_save_before">
         <observer name="handle_order_attrs" instance="Custom\Payment\Observer\HandleOrderAttrs" />
      </event>
   </config>
```

> 3. Create an observer HandleOrderAttrs.php in Observer folder

```
<?php

   namespace Custom\Payment\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 
   use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver; 
   use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

   class HandleOrderAttrs implements ObserverInterface
   {
      protected $checkoutSession;
      protected $_inputParamsResolver;
      protected $_quoteRepository;
      protected $logger;
      protected $_state;

      public function __construct(
         \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver $inputParamsResolver,
         \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
         \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
         \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
         CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
      ) {
         $this->_inputParamsResolver = $inputParamsResolver;
         $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
         $this->logger = $logger;
         $this->_state = $state;
         $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
      }

      public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
      {
         $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();

         foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
            if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
               $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
               $method = $inputParam->getData('method');
               $paymentOrder = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
               // $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder();
               // $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
               // $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();
               // $method = $paymentQuote->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
               if ($method == 'custompayment') {
                  if(isset($paymentData['cc_owner'])) {
                  // $paymentQuote->setData('cc_owner', $paymentData['cc_owner']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setData('cc_owner', $paymentData['cc_owner']);
                  // $paymentQuote->setData('cc_exp_month', $paymentData['cc_exp_month']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setData('cc_exp_month', $paymentData['cc_exp_month']);
                  // $paymentQuote->setData('cc_exp_year', $paymentData['cc_exp_year']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setData('cc_exp_year', $paymentData['cc_exp_year']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Credit Card Number',
                  $paymentData['cc_number']);                        
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Expiration Month ',
                  $paymentData['cc_exp_month']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Expiration Year ',
                  $paymentData['cc_exp_year']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Name ',
                  $paymentData['cc_owner']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Ext. ',
                  $paymentData['cc_ext']);
                  // $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Phone',
                  $paymentData['cc_phone']);        
                  $this->checkoutSession->start();                       
                  $this->checkoutSession->setCustomerName($paymentData['cc_owner']);
                  $this->checkoutSession->setCardNumber($paymentData['cc_number']);
                  $this->checkoutSession->setExt($paymentData['cc_ext']);
                  $this->checkoutSession->setPhoneNumber($paymentData['cc_phone']);
                  $this->checkoutSession->setExpMonth($paymentData['cc_exp_month']);
                  $this->checkoutSession->setExpYear($paymentData['cc_exp_year']);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         return $this;   
      }
   }
```

Comment: Followed this but it wont send day and time along with data after selected by customer.

Comment: After adding getData : function() in your js file -  you have to check that data in observer.  
$paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');  
Here you need to var_dump or print_r($paymentData);

Also you need to uncomment these

 //$order = $paymentOrder->getOrder();
  // $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
  // $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();

Comment: Followed above steps but still same result. Is there anything else i can try?
Really appreciate your help, Thanks man.

Comment: This is the way i got same type of data in my custom payment method. you have to work through it.

Comment: where did you set methods for setCustomerName etc?

Comment: $paymentQuote->setData('cc_owner', $paymentData['cc_owner']); 
This set data in cc_owner in quote_payment table . same way you can add data to any field in quote_payment or quote table.

 $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());

now you can set any entity in quote table by doing :
$quote>setData('customer_gender', 'Male' );

Comment: $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
This code works from quote table but what to use for sales_order table?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try 
> $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder(); 
>  $order>setData('field_name', 'value');

Comment: Please up-vote the answer if its useful.

Comment: Did you get what you wanted ? Please tell how did you implement this.